# Nested Lists/Collections of Lists

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a Discord Bot that manages a Raffle system. I need the bot to be able to dynamically create lists of raffle entries as raffles are created inside of my Raffle class (1 list per raffle). I could use a two-dimensional array for this, by I've used lists for everything else up to this point and I like the ease of use of them. What is the best way to use lists to accomplish this in VB.net? The nested list examples ive seen on the internet so far were a bit difficult to wrap my head around.

```
    Private RaffleIDList As New List(Of Integer)
    Private RaffleNameList As New List(Of String)
    Private RaffleCountdownList As New List(Of Integer)
    Private RaffleMinimumEntriesList As New List(Of Integer)
    Private RaffleRewardTitleList As New List(Of String)
    Private RaffleRewardLinkList As New List(Of String)
    Private RaffleGoLiveList As New List(Of DateTime)

    'TODO: Improve Entry storage to allow lists for each Raffle
    Private RaffleEntries As New List(Of Discord.IUser)

    Function addRaffle(ByVal RaffleName As String, ByVal RaffleCountdown As Integer, ByVal RaffleMinimumEntries As Integer, ByVal RaffleRewardTitle As String, ByVal RaffleRewardLink As String, ByVal RaffleGoLive As DateTime) As Integer

        'Ensure all required perameters are provided and valid
        If RaffleName <> Nothing Then
            'Return RaffleID if creation is succesful

            Dim newId As Integer = getNewRaffleID()

            'Add Raffle
            RaffleIDList.Add(newId)
            RaffleNameList.Add(RaffleName)
            RaffleCountdownList.Add(RaffleCountdown)
            RaffleMinimumEntriesList.Add(RaffleMinimumEntries)
            RaffleRewardTitleList.Add(RaffleRewardTitle)
            RaffleRewardLinkList.Add(RaffleRewardLink)
            RaffleGoLiveList.Add(RaffleGoLive)

            Return newId

        End If

        'Return failure if not passed above.
        Return -1
    End Function
```

The provided code is within my Raffle class and shows my Raffle variables and the addRAffle() function. Currently, I am only declaring a single list (RaffleEntries) to hold the entries (of Discord.Iuser), but what I really need is the ability to have a separate entry list for each active raffle.

Comment: Is this your entire raffle class?  I've read over this about 10 times and to me (assuming this is your class) RaffleEntries is a property of Raffle.  and if that is the case, you've already answered your own question

Answer (score 1):

You appear to already be doing it wrong.  You should not have all those individual lists but rather a single list of a custom type.  You should define a `Raffle` class and it would have `ID`, `Name`, `Countdown`, ..., and `GoLive` properties.  It would also have an `Entries` property of type `List(Of Discord.IUser)`.  Each time you create a `Raffle` object, it already contains the inner list and it's accessible via that property.

E.g.

```
Public Class Raffle

    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
    '...
    Public Property GoLive As Date
    Public ReadOnly Property Entries As New List(Of Discord.IUser)

End Class
```

and sample usage:

```
Dim raffles As New List(Of Raffle)
Dim r As New Raffle With {.Id = 1,
                          .Name = "First",
                          .GoLive = Date.Today}

r.Entries.Add(entry1)
raffles.Add(r)
```

Comment: Indeed, this is how I should have set it up. Thanks for the help!